# Activerecord :condition syntax of an empty field?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails

What is the rails `activerecord` syntax for select records with an empty field? For example, I want to find all the records that the `middle_name` field is empty (length of the string < 1) for a `user` database. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rails 2

```
User.find(:all, :conditions=>["middle_name is  ? or middle_name = ?", nil, ''])
```

In Rails 3, you can also do it in following way

```
User.where("middle_name is  NULL or middle_name = ''")
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a .where()?